# Angular ChangeDetection not working for button disable attribute with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular

Using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to avoid checking the page for changes again and again, but I call it explicitly `ChangeDetection` when I need it.

I have `ReactiveForm` with the validation:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
 station: ['', Validators.required],
 startDate: ['', Validators.required],
 endDate: ['', Validators.required],
 dataType: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

HTML Markup for button:

```
<button [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
```

When last input is changed, I call the following:

```
dateChange() {
  console.log(this.form.valid)
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

The console returns `true` but the button does not enable (not clickable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `markForCheck()` instead of `detectChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

You're using OnPush, why not use an Observable and async pipe to control the state of the form instead of manually triggering a change detection? It seems counter-productive to me to do both?

```
<button [disabled]="!(dataSource$ | async)">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button [disabled]="!form.valid || null">Submit</button>
```

disabled is an HTML attribute, as long as it has a value it is set.... Changing it to null instead of false should do the trick.

Comment: What you are saying is to put `false` will also disable the button? Which does not.

Comment: Putting false does NOT disable. it has to be null

Comment: I did what you suggested but does not help.

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz?